# Misc file corruption freebsd 10 and dns zone file

Tags: filesystems, freebsd, dns, bind, ufs

The computer is a VPS from Vultr. They tell me that "since it is loaded into RAM and not really a drive, nothing on the host would be causing this."

One particular file, my zone file, will come up corrupted for no reason. I have had to replace it from backup a couple of times.
I have found other corrupted files (one or two) over the past couple of months. But I am in my dns a lot a the whole world knows when this file explodes/dies.

No errors in dmesg, I ran a file system check at boot and 2 weeks later, same thing.

Where would I look to find the root cause of this file corruption and fix it?
.
[Lots of output](http://paste.ee/p/LofCE)

Comment: Bad disk?  Bad RAM?  System pwned? :)

Comment: @ lcd047 It's a VPS from Vultr so I am very limited in the diagnostics I can perform on the actual hardware (I should mention this in my question, I will update). They tell me that it's just memory and nothing the host is doing could be causing it. I really don't know.